# Overlaying an img div over a text div

Tags: html, css

I've built a website for a hotel. All that is left is the last part.

What I want the last section to contain is three images; on hover they slide down to show a text `<div>` underneath. Everything works except positioning the images on top of the texts to hide them.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1rzekcf/)
and to simplify a bit more:

```
Page Parent Div; 
then a div to contain the texts;
and three text divs;

new Div to contain all three imgs;
then each img in seperate divs;
```

If you guys have any notes on my code I'm all ears, especially on the horizontal list alignment and just for the notes,

**How can I control the `<div>`s being flexible when someone resizes the browser window with my website up?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble fully understanding what you are asking so I'm interpreting the question as "three images; on hover they slide down to show a 
text `<div>` underneath".

The way I would approach this is to have two divs (the text and image) placed within another container div.

```
<div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="itemText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse facilisis augue vel purus fermentum, quis accumsan urna accumsan.
    </div>
    <div class="itemImage">
        <img src = "287.jpg" width="300px" height="200px">
    </div>
</div>
```

The use the CSS transition to move the image div by the height of the text div downwards using the top style property.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.itemContainer
{
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
}    

div.itemText
{
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}

div.itemImage
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}

div.itemContainer:hover > div.itemImage
{
    top: 200px;
}
</style>
```

JSFiddle of code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/p2xkLaku/

You will need to set the height of the container in the top property in

```
div.itemContainer:hover > div.itemImage
```

You could set this up to adjust automatically using JavaScript.

To change the amount of time for the transition to occur change the 1s values in the below lines.

```
-webkit-transition: top 1s;
transition: top 1s;
```